# Rails - forms fields for arrays

Tags: ruby-on-rails

For my model containing array field `arr`

(in HAML)

```
= form_for @model do |f|
    - @model.arr.try(:each) do |i|
        = text_field_tag 'model[arr][]', i
```

How can I use `f` when I'm creating my text fields?

As you can see, I am ignoring `f` and manually specifying everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can. For serialized attributes, the approach you are taking is the only one I know of.